# select a neighborhood of points and convert it to a vector

Tags: r, image-processing, machine-learning

I have a data that is actually an image in form of 256 x 256 matrix. I want to select a neighborhood of points and convert it to a vector. Then apply some clustering algorithms. I am new to R and need some help with the code. I have created a toy dataset to show what I want to do.

```
d<- matrix(rbinom(8*8,1,0.5),8,8)
d
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
[2,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1
[4,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    1    1
[6,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
[7,]    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    0
[8,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    0
```

Starting at point d[2,2], I want to select a neighborhood of 8 points around it and convert it into a vector. So for d[2,2] those points will be top 3 d[1,1],d[1,2],d[1,3], adjacent left d[2,1] adjacent right d[2,3] and bottom 3 d[3,1],d[3,2] and d[3,3]. That will be as follows:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

Now convert it to a vector in R^9 as v1=(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1). Then, I want to do this for all points that are not on boundry of matrix (i.e. first and last rows and first and last columns). I have not idea how to proceed and will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can proceed with a nested `for` loop:

```
ddim <- dim(d) - 1
vect <- list()
for(i in seq(ddim[1])[-1]) {
    for(j in seq(ddim[2])[-1]) {
        vect <- c(vect, list(c(d[(i-1):(i+1), (j-1):(j+1)])))
    }
}
```

There may be optimised solution (nested for loop is bad) but this works if you're not too burdened with data.

Comment: Thanks.But I would like to store vect in a matrix. How do I do that ?

Comment: you can add  `do.call(cbind, vect)`